# Multiplying sparse matrix in crs-format by itself and get the product

Tags: c, matrix, compression, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to compare the speedup of NxN matrix multiplication by using the classical naive way vs. using compressed row storage. The values in the matrix are binary, either 0 or 1.

In the classical matrix multiplication, multiplying the matrix by itself is straightforward given as:

```
   for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
           product[i][j] += mat[i][k]*mat[k][j];
        }
        
        }
        }
```

In the compressed row storage format, I am required to store the matrix in an array, col_idx, which stores all the column indices of the non-zero values. I also need a row pointer, which encodes the index in col_idx where the given row starts.

For example if we multiply the following matrix by itself, we have the product:

[Matrix Mult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILe5w.gif)

The column index and row pointer in the given matrix will then have the array values:

```
col_idx = [1,2,2,3,0,3,1]
row_ptr = [0,2,4,6,7]
```

To get the column indices of one row, say the very first row, I simply have to code in:

```
    for (i = row_ptr[0]; i < row_ptr[1]; i++) {
    printf("%d\n",col_idx[i]);
}
```

I want to have the same product as in the classical matrix multiplication for the CRS-algorithm, but in a 1D-array that only stores the non-zero values, which in this example would be:

```
product1D = [1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1]
```

I've tried to get all rows at the same time, but I'm stuck on what I should do forward. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation in **https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operations-sparse-matrices/** (C++) is good :

```
void multiply(sparse_matrix b) 
{ 
    if (col != b.row) 
    { 

        // Invalid multiplication 
        cout << "Can't multiply, Invalid dimensions"; 
        return; 
    } 

    // transpose b to compare row 
    // and col values and to add them at the end 
    b = b.transpose(); 
    int apos, bpos; 

    // result matrix of dimension row X b.col 
    // however b has been transposed, 
    // hence row X b.row 
    sparse_matrix result(row, b.row); 

    // iterate over all elements of A 
    for (apos = 0; apos < len;) 
    { 

        // current row of result matrix 
        int r = data[apos][0]; 

        // iterate over all elements of B 
        for (bpos = 0; bpos < b.len;) 
        { 

            // current column of result matrix 
            // data[,0] used as b is transposed 
            int c = b.data[bpos][0]; 

            // temporary pointers created to add all 
            // multiplied values to obtain current 
            // element of result matrix 
            int tempa = apos; 
            int tempb = bpos; 

            int sum = 0; 

            // iterate over all elements with 
            // same row and col value 
            // to calculate result[r] 
            while (tempa < len && data[tempa][0] == r && 
                   tempb < b.len && b.data[tempb][0] == c) 
            { 
                if (data[tempa][1] < b.data[tempb][1]) 

                    // skip a 
                    tempa++; 

                else if (data[tempa][1] > b.data[tempb][1]) 

                    // skip b 
                    tempb++; 
                else

                    // same col, so multiply and increment 
                    sum += data[tempa++][2] *  
                         b.data[tempb++][2]; 
            } 

            // insert sum obtained in result[r] 
            // if its not equal to 0 
            if (sum != 0) 
                result.insert(r, c, sum); 

            while (bpos < b.len &&  
                   b.data[bpos][0] == c) 

                // jump to next column 
                bpos++; 
        } 
        while (apos < len && data[apos][0] == r) 

            // jump to next row 
            apos++; 
    } 
    result.print(); 
}
```

The C++ constructor of a sparse matrix is defined in this like

```
 sparse_matrix(int r, int c) 
{ 

    // initialize row 
    row = r; 

    // initialize col 
    col = c; 

    // initialize length to 0 
    len = 0; 

    //Array of Pointer to make a matrix 
    data = new int *[MAX]; 

    // Array representation 
    // of sparse matrix 
    //[,0] represents row 
    //[,1] represents col 
    //[,2] represents value 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) 
        data[i] = new int[3]; 
}
```

with `int** data`

In **https://codingee.com/c-programs/c-program-for-multiplication-of-two-sparse-matrices/** is C code

Comment: That is not a csr matrix, that's a triplet matrix. OP Asked for csr.